# Showing unread count in navbar

Tags: javascript, python, json, django

So I've currently got this function in my views.py

```
def live_unread_notification_count(request):
    unread_notifications = Notification.objects.all_for_user(request.user).unread().count()
    data = {
        "unread_notifications": unread_notifications,
    }
    json_data = json.dumps(data)
    return HttpResponse(json_data, content_type='application/json')
    print data
```

i have my url

```
url(r'^notifications/unread_count/$', 'live_unread_notification_count', name='live_unread_notification_count'),
```

and i get the right number of notifications when i got to the url e.g

```
{"unread_notifications": 2}
```

How to i now display this on my Navbar in the html template when the person refreshes the page?

Do i need some javascript?

Please help.

Comment: If you're fetching notification count via AJAX, yes, you need JS. But if you want to show notification count only when page is accessed, you can just pass the notification count to your template context.

Comment: you are using the django notifications package?

Comment: @xyres thanks! ive got it so that it shows up every time i go to the Url above so /unread_count/ how to i get it so it shows on every page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll use jQuery to demonstrate.

First, give the element an `id` inside which you want to show the notification count.

For example:

```
<span id="notifCount"></span>
```

Now, let's get to the JS part:

```
<!-- Put this code before the body tag ends -->

<!-- Load jQuery -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- JS code to fetch notif count -->
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '{% url "live_unread_notification_count" %}',
        method: 'GET',
        success: function(data) {

            // assign the count to a variable
            var unreadNotifs = data['unread_notifications'];

            // put the count in the notifCount element
            $('#notifCount').html(unreadNotifs);
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

---

This anwer provides a starting point for you to get started with JS, jQuery and AJAX.
Read about these topics. Withing a couple of days you should be good to go.